# Hibernate Skip and take some rows

Tags: java, hibernate

How to get let's say 20-35 rows fromt eh table?

How can I select it in Hibernate?

something like that:

```
myTable.Skip(20).Take(15);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A combination between [`Query#setFirstResult(int i)`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setFirstResult(int)) and [`Query#setMaxResults(int i)`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setMaxResults(int)) will skip the first `20` records and will fetch the next `15` (as shown in the example) :

```
List<Table> page3 = session.createQuery(
      "from Table")
      .setFirstResult(20)
      .setMaxResults(15).list();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<YourTable> query = session.createQuery("from yourtable").setFirstResult(20).setMaxResults(15).list();
```

Comment: What is new in your answer ? It's exactly same as @kocko answer.

Comment: i didn't see his answer
i just answered the question ;)

Comment: When u added, you must saw that whether ur answer is match with somebody else or not. Right ? If u r the 1st who answered this then no issue but, it's not the case here. Either update or delete it.